# PropertyDescriptor - Exception with SetValue() while GetValue() works

Tags: c#, propertydescriptor

I have an object that I have defined and I wish to modify one of its property called "DeviceType" using PropertyDescriptor but it's not working out for me.

I can retrieve the value of the property DeviceType but when I use SetValue() to change its property value, I always get the exception: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" even if I try to set the property to the same value that I just retrieved.

Here is some code:

```
PropertyDescriptorCollection properties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(theBase);
var objValue = properties["DeviceType"].GetValue(theBase);

try 
{
    if (theBase != null && objValue != null)
    {
        properties["DeviceType"].SetValue(theBase, objValue);
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{

}
```

Any help would be much appreciated. 
Thanks.

Comment: Does the property have a setter?

Comment: It's possible the null reference exception is coming from within the DeviceType setter

Comment: @leppie: Thanks for your response. Yup, the property does have a setter.

Comment: @pickles: That might be the case. I'll do more digging and see what I can find. (I'm working on top of existing code) Thanks.

Comment: Thanks again guys. The null exception was coming from the setter. The property was not initialized correct when theBase object was created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property was not initialized correctly when my object was created and so the setter property was generating a null reference exception error.